# Ruby on Rails Active Admin image Placeholders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, activeadmin

I am using activeadmin as the admin interface for an application I am working on and am trying to work out how to get image URL's to display as placeholders if an image is already uploaded.

Activeadmin works using simpleform so in theory it should be relatively easy but I seem to be struggling.

The code I currently have is:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Place do
...
show do |place|
    attributes_table do
    ...
    (1..6).each do |i|
        row(:"image_#{i}") do
          if place.send("image_#{i}").present?
            image_tag(place.send("image_#{i}").index)
          else
            "None"
          end
        end
      end
      (1..6).each do |i|
        row(:"mood_board_image_#{i}") do
          if place.send("mood_board_image_#{i}").present?
            image_tag(place.("mood_board_image_#{i}").index)
          else
            "None"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
....
end
```

At the moment I am just getting the default 'No file chosen' text when in the activeadmin interface. Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: What is the result of this row: place.send("image_#{i}").index ?

Comment: @nistvan thanks for your reply. The result is a button that says 'Choose File' and then accompanying text to the right that says 'No File chosen' this is despite there definitely being a file there as it loads the image in the views outside of the admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

The first arg in image_tag should be the source of the image:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

```
if 'there is image url'
  image_tag(url_of_the_image)
else
  #your_button_whit_your_text
end
```